# How to make two simple node applications talk to one another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I want to create two node applications that that talk to one another.
for an example first node application should serve "hello from app 2" and the response should be taken from second application. similarly second node application should serve "hello from app 1" and this should be fetched from application 1.

Here is some code that i have tried for node app 1

```
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req,res)=> res.send('Hellofrom first app'));
app.get('/hellofrom', (req,res)=> res.redirect('http://localhost:3002/'));

app.listen(3003, () => {
    console.log ('This is my first app');
})
```

for node app 2

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req,res)=> res.send('Hellofrom second app'));
app.get('/hellofrom', (req,res)=> res.redirect('http://localhost:3003/'));

app.listen(3002, () => {
    console.log ('This is my second app');
})
```

apparently i tried to redirect it but that is not the case. i used express but i'm open for other frameworks.

Comment: I think this link will help you
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30163915/16924632)

Comment: `res.redirect()` does not make a connection to the other server. Instead it **replies** with code 302 (instead of the normal 200) and a header telling the browser where it should be redirected to. It is the browser that connects to the other server. If you are NOT using a browser (eg. if you are using Postman or your own custom client code) then you need to manually connect to the other server..

Comment: .. If you want to fetch data from the other server (like you normally do with a database or Facebook API or Google API etc.) then you will need to make a http connection. You can use the built-in http client but I'd suggest something like `node-fetch` or `axios` for a better API